# jQuery getting all input elements of type text where the id ends in "Source"

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to get all text boxes that have an id that ends in a particular string.

So far I have tried

```
$("input[id$='Source']").each(function() {

$("input[type=text][id$='Source']").each(function() {
```

and also

```
$("input[type=text] , [id$='Source']").each(function() {
```

none of these seem to work, could some one maybe point me in the right direction.

I have tried clearing my web browsers cache just to make sure it was not caching any old code.

Comment: Post some of the HTML -> also check the console, any errors?

Comment: Your use of quotes is a bit inconsistent. Without testing it this should work: `$("input[type='text'][id$='Source']")`

Comment: @tymeJV I will post some of the HTML later, I will have to clean out some stuff that I can not post first, and to your second question, I have watched the javascript console and I don't see any errors in there.  the only message in there is ":visited and :link styles can only differ by color. Some styles were not applied to :visited." and I doubt that that would have any effect on the code i am looking at.

Comment: The first two selectors you posted both works. This indicates the problem lies somewhere else. Perhaps a missing semicolon or something along that path.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works:

```
<input type="text" id="mysource">
<input type="text" id="yoursource">
<input type="text" id="nope">
```

js (the context 'this' inside of the each function will be the matched elements):

```
$("input[type='text'][id$='source']").each(function() {
    console.log(this);
});
```

console result:

```
<input type="text" id="mysource">
<input type="text" id="yoursource">
```

Answer (score 2):

Clean up your quotes and you should be OK -

```
$('input[id$="Source"]').each(function() {

$('input[type="text"][id$="Source"]').each(function() {
```

Here is an example fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/C5v4H/

Comment: Yes, they are - but it is very clean and matches markup.

Comment: The quotes may be redundant but if you ever try to match a value with spaces you'll need them anyway - thus going with the quotes is consistently clean/works.  e.g. `input[title="Hello World"]` is better.